# Safari date difference gives nan

Tags: javascript, date, safari

i'm using a function to subtract a specific date and time from todays date and time

```
<script>
function timeDifference(previous) {

    var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
    var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
    var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
    var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
    var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

    var elapsed = new Date() - new Date(previous);

    if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
        return Math.round(elapsed/1000) + ' seconds ago';
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
        return Math.round(elapsed/msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {
        return Math.round(elapsed/msPerHour ) + ' hours ago';
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
        return Math.round(elapsed/msPerDay) + ' days ago';
    }

    else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
        return  Math.round(elapsed/msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
    }

    else {
        return Math.round(elapsed/msPerYear ) + ' years ago';
    }
}
</script>
```

this function works perfectly on firefox,chrome but give NaN on safari
any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Used moment instead of date, every thing works fine

```
 <script>
function timeDifference(previous) {

var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;

var elapsed = new moment() - new moment(previous);

if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
    return Math.round(elapsed/1000) + ' seconds ago';
}

else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
    return Math.round(elapsed/msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';
}

else if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {
    return Math.round(elapsed/msPerHour ) + ' hours ago';
}

else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
    return Math.round(elapsed/msPerDay) + ' days ago';
}

else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
    return  Math.round(elapsed/msPerMonth) + ' months ago';
}

else {
    return Math.round(elapsed/msPerYear ) + ' years ago';
}
}
 </script>
```